# Using @for loop in scss

Tags: loops, for-loop, sass

I need to create a ´@for´ loop in SCSS that loops from 1 to 100 and correspondingly adds the number to a class. I have a class ´width-percentage-x´, and the x should a number corresponding to the index of the loop. I can't figure out what i am doing wrong!

```html
    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
        .width-percentage-#{$i} {
            img {
                width: $i%;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case, if it is `width-percentage-30`, the `img` within this `div` should have `width:30%;`. This loop creates the list of classes that i need but doesn't add the corresponding `width` to the `img`, for some reason it only renders `width:50%;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use calc:

```scss
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .width-percentage :nth-child(#{$i}) {
        width: calc(#{$i}% + 0px);
        border: 1px solid #f99;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/saravanapriyanm/pen/QWYjyEd

Answer (score -2):

It seems my syntax was slightly wrong!

```html
    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
        .width-percentage-#{$i} {
            img {
                width: 0% + $i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Like this it works now!

Comment: You might want to use a better editor, like Sublime Text, for simple syntax errors.